# Привязка имени сетевого интерфейса к MAC-адресу

Tags: linux, интерфейс

Имеется два беспроводных адаптера, которые при загрузке получают идентификаторы `wlan0` и `wlan1` соответственно. При этом первый адаптер всегда стоит в системе, а второй может меняться.
Мне нужно, чтобы идентификатор `wlan0` всегда привязывался к адаптеру с MAC-адресом `AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA`, а идентификатор `wlan1` всегда получал другой адаптер.
Я создал файл /etc/udev/rules.d/10-network.rules со следующим содержимым

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ATTRS{address}=="aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa", NAME="wlan0"
```

Однако при загрузке ОС иногда возникает ситуация, когда адаптер с MAC-адресом `AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA` получает идентификатор `wlan1`, следовательно, другой адаптер получает идентификатор `wlan0`. Естественно, при попытке смены идентификатора происходит ошибка и вместо `wlan0` первому адаптеру присваивается идентификатор `rename4`.
Можно ли как-то указать без конкретной привязки к MAC'у, чтобы второй адаптер всегда получал идентификатор `wlan1`?

```
$ grep -r wlan /etc/udev/rules.d /lib/udev/rules.d
/lib/udev/rules.d/10-network.rules:SUBSYSTEM=="net", ATTRS{address}=="aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa", NAME="wlan0"

$ grep -ir aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa /etc/udev/rules.d /lib/udev/rules.d
/lib/udev/rules.d/10-network.rules:SUBSYSTEM=="net", ATTRS{address}=="aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa", NAME="wlan0"
```

Comment: а что у вас в `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` лежит?

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, к тексту вопроса (нажав [edit]) вывод команды `$ grep -r wlan /etc/udev/rules.d /lib/udev/rules.d` и команды `$ grep -ir aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa /etc/udev/rules.d /lib/udev/rules.d` (где `aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa` — упоминаемый вами mac-адрес.

Comment: А в `/etc/udev/rules.d` вообще никаких фалов не лежит. Файлы есть только в `/lib/udev/rules.d` Файла `70-persistent-net.rules` в системе вообще нет. Операционка Kali Linux, если что.

Answer (score 1):

Интерфейс переименовывается одним из стандартных правил, а чистить их не стоит.

Используй имена не wlan0, wlan1, а что-то более аутентичное. Я использую netX для сетевых карт. Например wifi0, wifi1 смотрелось бы неплохо.